# in Binary Tree ,checking if given node is leaf node or not

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I have written the code to find if the given node is leaf node or not , It works fine for positive case , i.e. when the entered node is a leaf node , the code code traverse till the node and and if it is leaf node , gives the output and stops , but the negative scenario is failing when the entered node is not a leaf node, The code keeps traversing the complete tree even when it has passed through the node and it is not a leaf node.

```
boolean isLeaf(BTNode node, int data) {
   if (node == null) {
    return false;
   }
System.out.println("Node traversed :"+ node.data);
if (node.left == null && node.right == null && node.data == data) {
    System.out.println("Node : " + node.data + " is leaf node");
    return true;
}
return (isLeaf(node.left, data) || isLeaf(node.right, data));
}
```

Can any one tell what is the condition to stop the recursion if the node is found and  it is not a leaf node.

Thanks.

Comment: @Idos ,where should be the final return statement in the code you suggested, I added `return false;`  just before **final braces** , in that case the whole function returns false , even if the leaf node is found. With the current code , it will not compile because there is no final return.

Comment: (Edited to make it more simple to understand and to be similar to your code)

Comment: @Idos , the code will still throw compilation error, as it does not have final return statement. Also in your current code , we are not checking for given node , and even if we add the node value argument in `isLeaf(BTNode node , int data)` and `return false` in end and `node.data==data` condition while returning true, the code keeps traversing other nodes , even if it has located the leaf node. I have run the code with all these changes, it does not give the desired answer. the code will work for finding all leaf nodes but not for checking if given node is leaf node or not.

Comment: check my edit, I think that is what you wanted -> it returns "finally" in all paths and check if a node is a leaf or not.

Comment: @Idos , Your First code , will give compilation error , I have checked.

Comment: did my second solution work?

Comment: @Idos , the second solution will work , when we are not using recursion for traversing to the node. I applied the solution such that , I am traversing the tree using search node solution and when I reach to that node , I call this method and and pass the searched node to this function , if the function returns true , then its leaf node. So your solution works for single time check. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
boolean isLeaf(BTNode node, int data) {
    if (node == null)       
        return false;
    if (node.left == null && node.right == null)      
        return true; 
    isLeaf(node.left); 
    isLeaf(node.right);      
}
```

The main problem with the way you implemented it is the line:

```
return (isLeaf(node.left, data) || isLeaf(node.right, data));
```

Did you think of what happens when you execute it actually?

Edit: If you just want to check if a node is a leaf do:

```
boolean isLeaf(BTNode node, int data) {
    if (node == null)
        return false;    
    if (node.right == null && node.left == null)
        return true;
    return false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because your code includes traversal for no obvious reason. Think about what this recursive call does -  `return (isLeaf(node.left, data) || isLeaf(node.right, data));` . That should most likely be `return false`

Answer (score 1):

```
bool isleaf(Node* root)
    {
        if(root->left==NULL && root->right==NULL) return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using plain C for a BST:

```
bool isLeaf(struct node *root, int data) {

    if (root == NULL)
        return false;

    if (root->data == data) {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    if (data > root->data)
        return isLeaf(root->right, data);
    else
        return isLeaf(root->left, data);
}
```

I think you need to traverse the tree using the search/insert approach using the property of a BST

For a Binary Tree (instead of a BST):

```
bool isLeafBtree(struct node *root, int data) {
    if (root == NULL)
        return false;
    if (root->data == data) {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    if (isLeaf(root->left, data) == true)
        return true;
    else
        return isLeaf(root->right, data);
}
```